# When Importing Parent No Children Follow | Blender Python

Tags: python, objects, add-on, import, parent

I was able to get the "parent" object to import but the child objects don't follow. Does anyone know how to do this? Here's the current code I have so far.

```
def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        cabinetTool = scene.cabinet_tool
        filepath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "BaseCabinetShellTwoFrontCuts.blend")

        with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=False) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.objects = [name for name in data_from.objects if name.startswith("BaseCabinetTwoFrontCuts")]

        for obj in data_to.objects:
            if obj is not None:
                bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

...and my model hierarchy...
[image]